Как работают activity
Я пришла в андроид разработку из WPF. В нём всё понятно и просто, в том числе из-за работы в ОС windows. Прилодение запускается в отдельном процессе, и между окнами разделяется общее адресное пространство, что позволяет создавать свои классы окон и передавать им ссылки на объекты.
В android с активностями так не получится. А если получится, то всех пугают утечкой памяти. Поэтому каждая активность как будто изолирована и может получать только копию данных через всякие intent и bundle.
В связи с этим у меня есть вопрос. Активности и другие компоненты, запускаются в отдельных процессах linux (может, дочерних) или всё-таки представляют отдельный поток одного общего процесса? Несколько я знаю, там есть специальная программа в ос bindler вроде, и только она может запускать программы андроида. Спасибо за ответ!

они не изолированы. передача через intent и bundle нужна так же для того, чтобы при пересоздании активити (поворот экрана) данные остались в ней. мы можете использовать синглтон репозитории для хранения информации и получения ее в разных Активити. в манифесте для каждой активит можно указать отдельный android:process, что скорее всего и будет отдельным процессом. тогда, если в этом процессе произойдет ANR умрет только эта активити/сервис. остальные продолжат жить.

Но запуск активити возможен только через интент, соответственно, только андроид сам решает, когда получить инстанс от активности. Я пыталась перегрузить конструктор и сделать конструктор с параметрами - не получается. Увидела про синглтон, значит, всё-таки у компонентов общее адресное пространство. В итоге, напрямую передавать параметры нельзя, а значит, на системном уровне активности подразумевают, что они изолированы? Хотелось узнать, относительно Linux, запущенная активность - это отдельный системный процесс, или всё-таки поток? Я предполагаю, что это поток, контролируемый спец. программой.

Не стоит известные навыки WPF+Win пытаться притянуть в абсолютно другой рантайм. И Андроид это скорее виртуальная машина, чем Линукс. Тут больше аналогий с JVM, чем с Линуксом как таковым. Общение между компонентами приложения идет через intent и bundle потому, что IPC (inter-process communication) идет из коробки. Сегодня все сидят в одном процессе, завтра перенесли сервис в отдельный процесс а все как работало так и работает. Начнете костылить с сиглтонами и прямым доступам к системой созданным обьектам -- все посыпется. https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads

Спасибо за ссылку!

нашел лекции с учебы по этом теме
•Каждое приложение Android, установленное на устройстве, работает в собственной "песочнице" (изолированной программной среде)
•операционная система Android представляет собой многопользовательскую систему Linux, в которой каждое приложение является отдельным пользователем;
•по умолчанию система назначает каждому приложению уникальный идентификатор пользователя Linux (этот идентификатор используется только системой и неизвестен приложению); система устанавливает полномочия для всех файлов в приложении, с тем чтобы доступ к ним был разрешен только пользователю с идентифика-тором, назначенным этому приложению;
•у каждого процесса имеется собственная виртуальная машина (ВМ), так что код приложения выполняется изолированно от других приложений;
•по умолчанию каждое приложение выполняется в собственном процессе Linux. Android запускает процесс, когда требуется выполнить какой-либо компонент приложения, а затем завершает процесс, когда он больше не нужен либо когда системе требуется освободить память для других приложений.
Таким образом система Android реализует принцип предоставления минимальных прав. То есть каждое приложение по умолчанию имеет доступ только к тем компонентам, которые ему необходимы для работы, и ни к каким другим. Благодаря этому формируется исключительно безопасная среда, в которой приложение не имеет доступа к недозволенным областям системы

Спасибо огромное за краткое и емкое изложение! Пока в интернетах начитаешься всякого, не поймёшь ничего. Главный вопрос, что приложение - это всё-таки термин android sdk, а не Linux. И то, что компоненты приложения могут запускаться независимо, но в общем на одно приложение один процесс - то, что уложило всё по полочкам! Действительно, если компоненты "филосовски" проектируются как независимые и исполнимые только bindler, для них не стоит проектировать зависимости на уровне процесса, а передавать все интентами и бандлами.
